# XCode shortcut key to dismiss warning/error highlights?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a shortcut key to dismiss the lines that get highlighted yellow and red for warnings and errors, instead of having to click one by one on the symbols in the gutter?

I have tried searching but this particular nugget of wisdom isn't easy to find, if indeed it's out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The shortcut you're looking for is Control-Command-M which corresponds to Issues->Show All Issues in Xcode's Key Bindings settings menu. You can change this shortcut to what ever you'd like, and it will toggle wether or not error messages will be visible on screen.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I never included "issues" in my search term :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already tried that or if that's what you're searching, but there is the menu "Editor" -> "Issues" -> "Hide all issues" command that maybe can be useful

Comment: Spot on! Thanks. I never thought of looking under the Editor menu for this particular feature.